# How to combine data from two different tables into a variable

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone tell me how I can compare a variable that stores a country with 2 tables in the database?

I have this data in the database:

```html
 country            values
PT|AU|USA       0.03|0.04|0.05
```

And I have a variable that will store one of three values: EN, AU, USA
I would like this to get the data from the two tables but in the correct order.

```html
PT      => 0.03
AU      => 0.04
USA     => 0.05
```

I tried this way but it didn't work

```html
$countries  = $get1x["country"];
$values     = $get1x["values"];

$tags    = explode('|' , $countries);
$tags2   = explode('|' , $values);

$country  = "";
$value    = 0.0;

foreach($tags as $i => $key) {
    $i > 0;
    $value = str_split($key, $ii);
}
foreach($tags2 as $i2 => $key2) {
    $i2 > 0;
    $value = str_split($key2, $iii);
}

print_r($country);
```

Can anyone tell me a way?

Comment: what exactly do you want to do? Can you be more clear?

Comment: `explode` on `|` and `array_combine` . check my answer.

Comment: Sorry for delay, thanks so much

Comment: I can't tell for sure as you didn't show us any database related code, but: this should most likely be solved on DB level, not application (PHP-code) level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use`explode` and `array_combine()`, i.e:

```
$countries  = explode("|", "PT|AU|USA") ;
$values     = explode("|", "0.03|0.04|0.05") ;
$combined = array_combine($countries, $values);
print_r($combined);
```

---

```
Array
(
    [PT] => 0.03
    [AU] => 0.04
    [USA] => 0.05
)
```

---

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/ArKZRr)

Comment: sorry for delay, i see now. Thanks so much